# Pattern for adapting dynamically created UIViewController behavior to Android?

Tags: android, architecture, viewcontroller, abstraction

## Preface

We may be idiots for trying to pull this off. Our core competency is iOS not Android. To be honest, we're hoping that we're missing some major league basic thing about Android architecture.

## Problem

We have an iOS app architecture that dynamically assembles and presents UIViewControllers based on all sorts of data and logic. A group of DisplayManagers (our terminology) evaluate various data to dynamically create, configure, and present the UIViewControllers of the app.

We are completely stumped on how to approach adapting this pattern to Android.

Core issues:

1. An Activity is the rough equivalent of a UIViewController. Unfortunately, UIViewControllers can be combined, displayed contiguously (multiple in one view), and created without being presented. Activities cannot.
2. When you start an Activity there is no way (as far we can tell) to keep a reference to it and update it/be updated by it. We know that you can pass initial values in the intent...but what if a particular Activity needs to be updated based on an event inside a Singleton? Yes you can do this with LocalBroadcastManager - we're just not sure sending a thousand broadcasts throughout our app is the right pattern.
3. An Activity cannot exist without being in the navigation hierarchy - so if you don't want it to be usable you have to do weird things like overriding `onBackPressed()` and ensuring it's not touchable, etc.

## Use Case

This is by far NOT the only use case where we're facing this issue, but it's a good one to showcase our challenges.

We dynamically show, hide, and chain user prompts based on a variety of logic and data. That data can change in many ways, including realtime database changes (via Firebase). On iOS we have a `PromptManager` singleton that listens to the appropriate Firebase data and, any time the data it's listening to changes, evaluates whether a prompt should be shown.

On iOS, the `PromptManager` works in concert with a `PromptVC` to manage the possible chain of prompts. The `PromptManager` creates and manages a UINavigationController to show a series of prompts. The `PromptVC` only ever knows about the current prompt it's supposed to show. On a user interaction it notifies the `PromptManager` of the response and the `PromptManager` decides whether or not to then present another `PromptVC` with another prompt or dismiss the entire UINavigationController (that has been holding all the prompts).

**"So what's the problem? Just combine the `PromptManager` and the `PromptVC` into a `PromptActivity`."**

Ah, if only we could... What happens if a value change in Firebase should trigger a prompt? The `PromptActivity` would have to always exist and be ready to hear those changes - per "Core issues" above that is problematic. Furthermore, as stated, these prompts are one of MANY instances where changes need to happen based on Firebase data events, so we'd end up with dozens (or more) of Activities that are never shut down just because they're listening to Firebase references.

## The Ideal World

Singleton "DisplayManagers" are responsible for listening to data then creating/updating/managing/dismissing Activities. They interact with different Activities to show/hide themselves and update data within the current Activity. But to do this we need to be able to keep references to the activities we create from those Singletons.

Does anyone, for the love of all that is good in the world, know if a pattern like this is possible on Android? Because it's gorgeous on iOS...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definately use a single Activity for this, and use multiple Fragments.

Fragments can be created and destroyed with or without being shown first, so you can have full control over their lifecycle.

You can have multiple Fragments in 1 Activity.

And the Fragments could create the needed layout depending on what data is presented to them.

You should NEVER rely on an Activity that is currently not being shown. Those activities can be killed at any point by Android if it needs to free memory (extremely rare though, mostly on lower end phones).

To listen for Firebase events, you should have a Service that handles it.
The service is not tied to any Activity/Fragment directly, and lives on its own.

Then whenever you show a fragment, it would add a listener to the service. The service can then use that listener to inform the fragment of any incoming changes, and the fragment could act accordingly.

You should have a look at the RxAndroid library. It's literally built to adapt the UI based on incoming events from all kinds of sources, and to keep all data synchronized.

Feel free to ask any questions if you have doubts, but this kind of setup is definitely possible on Android.

EDIT:
Response to a comment (easier to write long messages here instead of in comments):
The Service would be bound to each Activity (called "Bound Services"), and the Activity would hold references to all Fragments in the Activity. So the service could call on the Activity, and the Activity would act accordingly (remove/add fragments, dismiss itself, etc).
This could also be the other way around, that the Activity calls on the service with some data, and the Service could do something (like call a backend API, or similar).

And the good thing about Services is that they inherit from Context. This means you can start new Activities directly from your Service.

PS: "were hoping to migrate our iOS implementations fairly directly to Android", thanks for the giggle :)

Comment: thanks for the response and willingness to help! Good point re: RxAndroid - we use RxJS for our web app version of this but we didn't use RxSwift and were hoping to migrate our iOS implementations fairly directly to Android (I know, the vain hope of mobile devs everywhere). We're definitely anticipating a healthy amount of Fragment manipulation inside an Activity but just aren't sure at what point to draw the line of abstraction. Great point re: relying on Activities. This just confirms our architecture decision to keep logic outside Activities.

Comment: Followup question then: if a Service becomes the thing that listens to Firebase and knows when particular Activities/Fragements might need to be added or removed or changed - how does it do that work and pass the results to the Activity? Essentially, our architecture would work great if a Service could manage Activities and their fragments (e.g. communicate to an NavigationActivity that a new TabBar Fragment needs to be added or receive a result from a PromptActivity, evaluate the result, then tell the PromptActivity to dismiss itself).

Comment: @BrockKlein check my editted answer for answers to your comments, and remember to accept/update if i helped :)

Comment: you're a saint! That's it. Hadn't explored Bound Services (again, iOS is our thing) - it was exactly what we needed. Glad you appreciated the laugh. :) Tho...once setting up our pattern with a Bound service our straight converted parts worked without any extra adjustments! We'll see how long that lasts. Thanks again for putting us on the right path!